# Centralizer of each element of a subgroup contained in the normalizer of the subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, permutation-groups

Let $G \leq \operatorname{Sym}(\Omega)$ be a permutational group. A base for $G$ is a sequence of elements of $\Omega$ whose pointwise stabilizer is the identity. A base is called irredundant if no point is fixed by the stabilizer of its predecessors. $G$ is said to be IBIS if all of its irredundant bases have the same cardinality. We set $b(G)$ to be the minimal size of a base of $G$.

Currently, I am working on the classification of almost simple IBIS group, and I came up with a particular condition of which I want to ask to you if you have ever seen it.
In particular, I noted that if $G$ is IBIS with $b(G)=3$, then, for $\alpha, \beta \in \Omega$ such that $\beta$ is not fixed by the stabilizer of $\alpha$, then
\begin{equation}
       C_G(x) \leq N_G(G_{\alpha} \cap G_{\beta}) \, \forall x \in G_{\alpha} \cap G_{\beta}.
\end{equation}
So I am wondering if it is possible to determine all the couples $(G,H)$, with $G$ an almost simple group, $H \leq G$ core-free, such that
\begin{equation}
        C_G(x) \leq N_G(H) \, \, \forall x \in H, \, x \neq 1.
\end{equation}

Comment: The set of all such couples would include pairs $(G,H)$ where $H$ is a TI-subgroup of $G$, right? There are already a lot of these! When you say "determine all", do you have a statement in mind? E.g. Such a pair $(G,H)$ either has $H$ a TI-subgroup of $G$ or **some nice list**? I guess you know of various families -- it would be good if you could give examples (e.g. $H$ any subgroup of form $O_p(B) \leq H \leq B$, for $B$ a Borel subgroup of $SL_2(2^a)$).